# How to use xml database in xampp

Tags: xml, database, xampp

I am having a project on faculty, and my PhD. Professor wants me to use only XML database, not MySQL database. So my question is how can I use an XML database on xampp, and which xml database should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database

'xampp' is just a bundle of preconfigured servers (mysql, apache + php). 
There is no relation between 'xampp' and usage of databases.

Update:
If you use php for your application backend and choose to use BaseX for database then check http://docs.basex.org/wiki/PHP_Example

Comment: Ok. I understand. But there i can create mysql databases. I would be able to work with xml databases? And if yes, how could I?

Comment: Unfortunately, the page referenced above PHP_Example was deleted from the BaseX site.  It has been replaced with a link to PHP-based example files out on github: https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/tree/master/basex-api/src/main/php